# How to get GroupBox default style WPF

Tags: xaml, wpf-controls

I need to get the `WPF` `GroupBox` default style, I googled it but in vain.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms744748%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

First link for me on google for "groupbox style" BTW

**Edit :**

You can have it from Expression Blend :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#D5DFE5"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="6"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                        <Border x:Name="Header" Grid.Column="1" Padding="3,1,3,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                            <Border.OpacityMask>
                                <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="7" Converter="{StaticResource BorderGapMaskConverter}">
                                    <Binding ElementName="Header" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Border.OpacityMask>
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3">
                                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

// CenterBorderGapMaskConverter code solve the issue

```
internal partial class CenterBorderGapMaskConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        // Methods
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Type type = typeof(double);
            if (values == null
                || values.Length != 3
                || values[0] == null
                || values[1] == null
                || values[2] == null
                || !type.IsAssignableFrom(values[0].GetType())
                || !type.IsAssignableFrom(values[1].GetType())
                || !type.IsAssignableFrom(values[2].GetType()))
            {
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            }

            double pixels = (double)values[0];
            double width = (double)values[1];
            double height = (double)values[2];
            if ((width == 0.0) || (height == 0.0))
            {
                return null;
            }
            Grid visual = new Grid();
            visual.Width = width;
            visual.Height = height;
            ColumnDefinition colDefinition1 = new ColumnDefinition();
            ColumnDefinition colDefinition2 = new ColumnDefinition();
            ColumnDefinition colDefinition3 = new ColumnDefinition();
            colDefinition1.Width = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);
            colDefinition2.Width = new GridLength(pixels);
            colDefinition3.Width = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);
            visual.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDefinition1);
            visual.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDefinition2);
            visual.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDefinition3);
            RowDefinition rowDefinition1 = new RowDefinition();
            RowDefinition rowDefinition2 = new RowDefinition();
            rowDefinition1.Height = new GridLength(height / 2.0);
            rowDefinition2.Height = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);
            visual.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition1);
            visual.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition2);
            Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle();
            Rectangle rectangle2 = new Rectangle();
            Rectangle rectangle3 = new Rectangle();
            rectangle1.Fill = Brushes.Black;
            rectangle2.Fill = Brushes.Black;
            rectangle3.Fill = Brushes.Black;
            Grid.SetRowSpan(rectangle1, 2);
            Grid.SetRow(rectangle1, 0);
            Grid.SetColumn(rectangle1, 0);
            Grid.SetRow(rectangle2, 1);
            Grid.SetColumn(rectangle2, 1);
            Grid.SetRowSpan(rectangle3, 2);
            Grid.SetRow(rectangle3, 0);
            Grid.SetColumn(rectangle3, 2);
            visual.Children.Add(rectangle1);
            visual.Children.Add(rectangle2);
            visual.Children.Add(rectangle3);
            return new VisualBrush(visual);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return new object[] { Binding.DoNothing };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but that's not the default style, if you want you can try it

Comment: OK but you need to explain what's BorderGapMaskConverter

Comment: It's a Microsoft converter designed for the groupbox in order to hide the border under the header content. See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.bordergapmaskconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more